# How to display the DPI value of a mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I'm trying to OCR an image in order to read the text on it. Original image is of 300 dpi.But all the ROI parts that are used as input parameters for Tesseract call are 96 dpi. I want to find out when is the quality drop happens. It will be possible if there is a way to calculate the DPI value of each vectors that are passed to Tesseract. Tesseract requires minimum 300 DPI for OCR.

Any idea?

Comment: "But all the ROI parts that are used as input parameters for Tesseract call are 96 dpi": how is this possible ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust That is what exactly i want to find out. In order to do that, i need to find out when did the quality drop happen.

Comment: If you don't tell us what you are doing, we cannot guess.